# driver for influence

Tags: transforms, drivers

I have this formula for my driver "1 if (var <= 0.4) else -1" and it works ok, but I want to add slow move from 1 to -1 and not just cut off. Or maybe slow down in the end 0 to -1. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suppose you want do a linear function to get the output from 0.3 to 0.4

$$
Let f(n) = An + B \\
\left\{\begin{align*}
&f(0.3)=A(0.3)+B=1\\
&f(0.4) = A(0.4)+B=-1\;
\end{align*}\right.\\
f(n) = -20n +7
$$

### So the expression:

```
1 if var < 0.3 else - 20 * min(0.4, var) + 7
```

Comment: I don't understand math at all but it works like magic :) thank you man!!!